# The Fastest Clean Draw

Tags: chess

[image]

Playing with regular moves, the position above should result in a draw without repeating
an exact position three times. By Helpmate or in this case a Helpdraw, players cooperate to end this game in a draw with agreed moves (white to play). How should this game be played or continued to end in a draw with fewest number of moves and least number of remaining pieces?

Comment: I assume you want the game to end in a stalemate? So the solution "White offers a draw, Black accepts" is not an option here?

Comment: Yes agreement to a draw  and stop playing is faster than 3 moves by 3 repeated position. But not an option here. Not 50 moves draw rule neither. (I edited the question for the intended  solution)

Comment: I haven't access to a board now but ___think___ this should work: rot13(1 o4 Aq6 2 o5 As7 3 Ot5 At5 4 Dq4 As3 5 qr Es6 6 r5 Aq4 7 Oo4 Oo4 8 Ao5 ½–½)

Comment: @msh210- 8 ...r5 capture Es6 ?? Stalemate wont work for least pieces on board. Try all capture moves.

Comment: Why the hard to read 3D board?

Comment: (setting of Chesscom) ..the board is not 3D just pieces w/o perspective

Comment: An edit to this question is [being discussed on Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6928/34791).

Comment: @Quintec- the illustration above is merely  positional information.. it is hard to think 9 moves ahead. Transfering the position to a real chess set or interactive chess apps is more practical. Try "chess.com" , click learn, click  analysis, click setup.. This is recommended for puzzle making and answering and there are lots of boards/pieces style to select from.

Comment: If the image is only for positional information, it should be given in a readable way. Using the weird perspective makes it difficult to tell apart the black pieces or to read the position as a whole.

Comment: @Nij - If 3D preference is there it is as good as any 2D preferences . Since younger chess players  today may be accustomed with "computer online games" and would prefer the flat set up.. I replace it to "2D classic".   Here is the PNG in case of copy paste [FEN "8/2n2R2/3RbN2/1n1B1rp1/K1pbrB2/2qPQN2/1Pk5/8 w - - 0 1"]

Comment: It's not about "preference", it's about being able to read the board at all. Accessibility is a thing for a reason.

Comment: @Nij - You  "not being able to read the board at all" ?  Why?

Comment: Honestly, if you're going to put more effort into questioning the legitimacy of an accessibility concern than resolving it, you're not worth explaining it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109432/discussion-between-tslf-and-nij).

Comment: To be clear, you want to draw on purpose, right, not because that is the best outcome? Because black to move is a mate in 1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Or not. I flipped the B & W sides. Still, I think it's worth fighting for a win as either player and not a draw. So you want to force a draw, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fewest remaining pieces:

> ```
>  1. Bxg5  Nxd6
>  2. Nxe4  Nxf7
>  3. Nxc3  Nxg5
>  4. Nxg5  Rxd5
>  5. Nxe6  Nxe6
>  6. Qxe6  Bxc3
>  7. bxc3  Rxd3
>  8. Qxc4  Rxc3
>  9. Qxc3+ Kxc3
>  K vs K stalemate
> ```

Least number of moves:

> ```
>  1. Bxc4 Rxe3
>  2. Bb3+ Qxb3+
>  3. Ka5  Nxd6+
>  4. Nd5  Bxf7
>  5. Nxg5 Rxg5
>  6. Be5  Rexe5
>  White has no legal move.
> ```

Comment: Isn't it possible to get 1 less remaining piece by having White capture the queen? (with a draw by impossibility of checkmate)

Comment: @Daniel Mathias - the fewest move to stalemate maybe 6 i cant find any lesser number of moves yet..and accepting this as right answer for stalemate..but the position was really set up  for 18 captures.

Comment: @TSLF Mission accomplished.

Comment: Nice draw by "insufficient pieces to force mate"